# How to write query in cakephp to find date between from date and last date

Tags: cakephp

I have to display posts where from_date AND last_date is in between current date.

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE status=1 AND CURDATE() between from_date AND last_date";`

As above query working fine, how I will convert above query in cakephp?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this page](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions).

```
$this->Post->find('all', array('conditions' => array(
     'status' => 1,
     'from_date BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array($from_date, $last_date)
)));
```

Comment: If current date is in between from_date AND last_date then only post will display. Where I will use CURDATE() in cakephp function?

Comment: try `'from_date BETWEEN ? AND CURDATE()'` and `array($from_date)`